# How can I tag the bookmarks in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I try to edit a bookmark in chrome but there's no where to tag it. Is it possible in Chrome?

Answer (score 22):

Google Chrome still does not support bookmark tags. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17536) is the official issue tracking page. It seems that the users badly need this feature.

One workaround can be to use [Delicious Bookmarks Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/delicious-bookmarks-exten/mnaelnkmidnndgikjbiifihgklnocljd) (Beta) till Google solves the problem.

Comment: If and when Google finally adds this feature, will there be an easy way to migrate tags from Delicious to the updated Chrome Bookmarks?

Comment: @bumbleshoot when Google finally adds the feature Delicious will probably be long forgotten

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote an extension to add tags to bookmarks in Chrome. It's the first release of the thing so not as beautiful as I would like but if you want to check it out here's the link...

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hmlmifgbfkhmjbjmmbhcichagfmmfdmp

Comment: Where are the tags stored?

Comment: @Nam - Sorry it took me so long to respond. I didn't get a notification for some reason of your comment. I store the bookmarks locally on the users system. At a future date I would like to add syncing and backup to a cloud system.

Comment: Thank you for your great skill of writting such an addon. But I don't think I need a tag stored locally then... it's gone.

Comment: This looks neat - not quite as nice as how it works in Firefox, but at least it's a start. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another Chrome Extension for tagging your bookmarks:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-tagger/dpiecafonfminhngabegejbligdagjfc

Tags are being saved in your local database.

Comment: Not in favor for a local database solution though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

And the other Chrome extension with tagging: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/taggable-bookmarks/cjcenjmpnolpeggnfbcogpdnacjejmga

There you can find target bookmarks via faceted search. Bookmarks are stored on the remote extension's server.

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to explain why you think this particular plugin is a good fit?